# Type error: myArr[i].splice is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror, splice

I've seen this question asked many times on stack overflow, however, I can't find a similar situation to understand what the issue could be. I have an array that I split based off of regex matches. I then run the string through a for loop. If the first letter isn't capitalized I perform an .toUpperCase on it. The issue is when I try to splice it back in. I'm able to perform the toUpperCase without any issue, however, the splice after the toUpperCase is giving me a type error. Could someone tell me why I'm having the issue and how to remedy it?

```
var sn = "i am done. i want candy! how are you? i am fine.";

function upperCasing(x){
   var myArr = x.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g );
   myArr.splice(0,0);
   for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
      if(myArr[i].charAt(1).match(/[a-z]/g)){
          var newArr = myArr[i].charAt(1).toUpperCase() + myArr[i].splice(0,1);
          console.log(newArr);
      }
  }
}

upperCasing(sn);
```

Working solution based off of the answers provided below plus I had to add a .trim();

```
var sn = "i am done. i want candy! how are you? i am fine.";

function upperCasing(x){
  var myArr = x.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g );
  myArr.splice(0,0);
  var newArr = [];
  console.log(myArr);
  for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
      //Trimmed unwanted white space caused by the space before each sentence.
      myArr[i] = myArr[i].trim();
      if(myArr[i].charAt(0).match(/[a-z]/g)){
          //Used substr method but changed it to 1 instead of 2
          newArr.push(myArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + myArr[i].substr(1));
      }
   }
   console.log(newArr.join(' '));
}

upperCasing(sn);
```

Comment: You're trying to spice the element of the array. Unless the array contains arrays, it doesn't make any sense. If you're trying to splice a string, you'll probably need to use the "prototype syntax".

Comment: You can [*slice*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.slice) a string though.

Comment: Are you trying to return the string from `upperCasing` call with substituted uppercase letters?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Array.prototype.splice()` where not necessary to return expected result. Defining `newArr` as variable within `for` loop does not return `newArr` from the function call. `.splice()` can remove elements from an `Array`, not a `String`.

Note also, `.charAt(0)` would be space character at indexes of `myArr` greater than `0`.

If you are trying to `return` the string following substitution for uppercase letter at start of string of `myArr` or following space character, you can use `Array.prototype.map()`, `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(\s?\w)/`, chain `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `""`.

```js
var sn = "i am done. i want candy! how are you? i am fine.";

function upperCasing(x){
   var myArr = x.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g );
   return myArr.map(function(text) {
     return text.replace(/(\s?\w)/, function(match) {
       return match.toUpperCase()
     })
   }).join("")
}

var res = upperCasing(sn);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you get the message about *splice*. ;-)

You can use other string methods instead, such as *slice*, *substr* and *substring*, which all work in slightly different ways. You have other issues with your code though:

1. Not matching the right sequence of characters to produce strings for capitalisation
2. Overwriting the value of *newArr* on each iteration.

Consider the following which has minimal changes:

```js
var sn = "i am done. i want candy! how are you? i am fine.";

function upperCasing(x){
  var myArr = x.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?] ?/g );
  var newArr = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
    if(/[a-z]/g.test(myArr[i].charAt(0))){
      newArr[i] = myArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + myArr[i].slice(1);
    }
  }
  console.log(newArr);
}

upperCasing(sn);
```

Or something a bit more hip:

```js
var sn = "i am done. i want candy! how are you? i am fine.";

function upperCasing(x) {
  return (x.match(/[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?] ?/g)||[]).map(function(part) {
    return part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.slice(1);
  }).join('');
}

console.log(upperCasing(sn));
```

Answer (score 1):

`splice` is Array method and cannot be called on string. You can convert string to an array, splice it and then convert it back to string:

```
let myArray = myArr[i].split('');
myArray.splice(0, 1);
splicedStr = myArray.join('');
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to @bartekfr's answer, use substring function.

```
var sn = "i am done. i want candy! how are you? i am fine.";

function upperCasing(x){
   var myArr = x.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g );
   for(var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
      if(myArr[i].charAt(1).match(/[a-z]/g)){
          var newArr = myArr[i].charAt(1).toUpperCase() + myArr[i].substr(2);
          console.log(newArr);
      }
  }
}

upperCasing(sn)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using splice on a string where as splice is only applicable on **Arrays**

[**Here You can get more information of splice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

For your reference I am also attaching screenshot of my console as well.

[image]